# Where is the su policy defined in Andriod SELinux Policy?

Tags: android-studio

Where the su policy is defined in the  SELinux policy and see what makes it different to other policies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is "su policy"?